# Java gRPC : Client unable to connect to a server with SSL enabled

Tags: java, ssl, grpc

I've got a gRPC server running with SSL enabled (using JDK as ALPN provider).
On the client side, I've created a channel and specified my truststore to contain server's public key certificate. This is how I've done it (according to official reference):

```
Channel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080)
        .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(new File("conf/server.crt")).build()).build();
```

With ssl debug enabled in JVM, I am getting following:

```
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, called closeOutbound()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, closeOutboundInternal()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, called closeInbound()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, called closeOutbound()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, closeOutboundInternal()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, called closeOutbound()
grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2, closeOutboundInternal()
```

The exceptions I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:210)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:191)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:124)
    at com.videobet.grpc.helloworld.HelloWorldServiceGrpc$HelloWorldServiceBlockingStub.greet(HelloWorldServiceGrpc.java:139)
    at client.MyClient.main(MyClient.java:21)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It looks like the server is hanging up on the client. Maybe the server is plaintext. Check the server for any error logs, as the client doesn't know what went wrong.